# Supersized jQuery plugin is not displaying the slideshow at www.acrews.com

Tags: jquery, plugins, slideshow, supersized

The slide show on my website stopped working some time in 2023 or even the end of 2022.  I am using a free web template called brush by alessioatzeni.com.

Website: [www.acrews.com](http://www.acrews.com)

I have tried  opening the site in different browsers.  I am using this code on another web site that is having the same issue.

Comment: Please see [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/328193)  Relevant code needs to be included in the question to produce a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem, as well as information about the problem itself and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.